# Symfony. Не могу обновить миграцию

Tags: symfony, миграция

После команды `bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff` была создана миграция.
После - `bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`

После пришлось внести изменение в entity и пересобрать миграцию этой же командой `bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff`. Но, почему-то получаю следушие ошибки:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT min_value, increment_by 
FROM "user_entity_id_seq"':  

SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "min_value" does 
not exist                     
LINE 1: SELECT min_value, increment_by FROM "user_entity_id_seq"  
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "min_value" does not exist  
LINE 1: SELECT min_value, increment_by FROM "user_entity_id_seq"
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "min_value" does not exist  
LINE 1: SELECT min_value, increment_by FROM "user_entity_id_seq"
```

Comment: а предыдущую миграцию отменяли?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, я пытался удалить по версии миграции `php bin/console doctrine migrations:version YYYYMMDDHHMMSS --delete` но, я не могу узнать версию, т.к. получаю ту же ошибку

Comment: попробуйте:1 `doctrine:migrations:migrate prev` 2. удалите php предыдущей миграции 3. `заново bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff`

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, да, это оно. В который раз меня выручаете. Спасибо! Добавьте как ответ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно поменять что-то в миграции, то можно:

Отменить предыдущую миграцию:

```
bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate prev
```

Удалить php-файл предыдущей миграции

Внести изменения в Entity

Заново выполнить:

```
bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```